# Get the latest date of records from a table, SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table like the following:

```
id    website       logInTime
1     Yahoo         1/1/2001 00:00:00
2     Google        1/1/2001 00:00:01
1     Yahoo         2/1/2014 00:00:00
2     Yahoo         2/1/2014 00:00:00
```

How can I retrieve the latest time of log in from each user based on the website?

Comment: use group by, and max(date)

Comment: For MS SQL .. `select website, max(logInTime) as maxLogInTime from YourTable group by website`

Comment: What database are you using?  What is the result that you expect from the data above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select t.id, t.website, max(logInTime)
from table t
group by t.id, t.website
```

Answer (score 5):

Is that the query you're looking for?

```
SELECT T.id
    ,T.website
    ,MAX(T.logInTime) AS [lastLogInTime]
FROM yourTable T
GROUP BY T.id, T.website
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Sorry you're right, i didn't notice that the id was referring to user. I fixed my query.

Answer (score 2):

this should work

```
select id
   , website
   , max(logInTime) as latesttime
from tableName

group by id, website
```